# Facebook: how to get the list of fan pages managed by a specific user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-page

I'm building a "website with Facebook login". After the user has logged in, I want to show the list of the Facebook Fan Pages that the user manages.

I know there is a way to do this, but I don't understand how the Graph API and FQL work.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function MyPages(user_id)
FB.api(
{
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT page_id,name from page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan       WHERE uid=' + user_id + ')'
},
function(response) {
    ...do something with response
});
```

This will give you pages he likes, so you'll have to replace page_fan with something else, but hopefully this will get you closer to your goal.